# iOS - Memory management

Tags: ios, arrays, memory-management

i have an array of custom class that is allocated in this way :

```
myArray = [NSMutableArray array];
```

I add object in it though a for loop :

```
for (CustomClass *obj in otherArray) {
    [myArray addObject:obj];
}
```

Then, i add all to my view :

```
CustomClass *obj = [myArray objectAtIndex:index];
[self.view addSubview:obj];
```

Every time i add the element in view i remove it from the array :

```
[myArray removeObject:obj];
```

At the end i have all the elements in my view. But, at the end of the game, i have to remove all objects from my view and remove also from memory. I use ARC. 
I don't know how to release objects also from memory.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to remove the object from every places it's stocked. ARC will handle for you the retain / release calls (at compile) to fall to zero when unused. You should notice that unreferenced object will no matter what be deallocated.

So you just have to keep in mind where your object is referenced :

### Array

When you add it into myArray it adds 1 to retain count.

When you remove it removes 1.

### View

When you addSubview it adds 1.

When you want to remove from super view you should call the removeFromSuperview selector on your item (I guess you know it and this isn't your question)

### First Array

I noticed it's your objects always stay in the otherArray array.

Comment: otherArray life cycle is this : otherArray = [NSMutableArray array] and it is populated in this way otherArray = [myInstanceOfCustomObject getElementsOfArray]. So, you think otherArray is the problem?

Comment: Because when i use Instruments i notice that some elements is not being released, but i thought that this objects were the subviews of my view. Subviews that i added from myArray.

Comment: One thing.. [otherArray removeAllObjects] removes 1 from all elements, right?

Comment: Yes the removeAllObjects will release all objects.

Comment: Are you sure every objects are removed from their superview ?

Comment: I use a for loop for this, cycling [[self view] subviews] and detect every objects which isKindOfClass:CustomClass class] and remove it from superview with removeFromSuperview. So, i suppose objects are removed from their superview.

Comment: So if your objects are not anymore referenced by any variable they'll be removed from memory. And keep in mind that ARC add itself the retain/release calls. You can't do it by yourself anymore. (try to add a release call you'll see an error)

Comment: Yes, i know. But Instruments shows that the objects are still in memory. Is it possible to see if the objects are referenced from array or as subviews?